# Three flexible spans in a container with one allowing text-overflow

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to get a scenario working in CSS, which places three texts side-by-side with no wrapping. Once the first text is too long, it has to be truncated.
See the picture below for a more detailed explanation.

What I tried so far:

- position texts in a row using float
- position texts in a row using flexbox
- position texts in a row using display: table-cell

As soon as the first text is longer than its container, things break. Either the container (or the text child) becomes larger than it should or the other two texts will be cut/hidden.

Does anybody have an idea to achieve a flexible layout as illustrated below?
Case 1 (any alternative) and Case 2 must be possible without knowing the width of the text.

[image]

Comment: On which browser should this work?

Comment: Just on the ones which support CSS3. All others can have fallback where the text either gets cut or truncated manually.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
 <div class="parent">
     <span class="third">
         Short
     </span>
     <span class="first">
         Short
     </span>
     <span class="second">
         Short
     </span>
 </div>

 <div class="parent">
     <span class="third">
         Short
     </span>
     <span class="first">
         LongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLong
     </span>
     <span class="second">
         Short
     </span>
 </div>

 <div class="parent">
     <span class="third">
         LongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLong
     </span>
     <span class="first">
         LongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLong
     </span>
     <span class="second">
         LongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLong
     </span>
 </div>
```

styled by:

```
 .parent{
     margin:10px;
     width: 400px;
     background-color:grey;
 }

 .parent span {
     overflow:hidden;
 }

 .first {
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     background-color:green;
     min-widh: 20%;
     float:left;
     max-width: 60%;
     display: inline-block;
 }

 .second {
     background-color:red;
     width: 20%;
     display: inline-block;
 }

 .third {
     float:right;
     background-color:yellow;
     width: 20%;
     display: inline-block;
 }
```

You can see how it looks here: http://jsfiddle.net/ramsesoriginal/utSgC/

I chose percentage-based widths as it allows you to simply set the width of the parent and the rest adapts.

The third example is just how it would react when second and third get really long...

Comment: Hi and thank you for your response!
Your example works only if the spans two and three have a fixed width, which is not the case in my situation. Maybe we get it working with flexible widths?

Comment: Ok, but how should two's and three's width be determined then? Because if one is flexible, and should grow, then two and three must shrink.. but how much? Is there a minimum length for them? Or a maximum length for one? Or both?

Comment: (I updated the jsfiddle with more cases, just so that I have all examples..)

Comment: Minimum of two and three would be their content. Once they're at minimum, one can no longer grow.

Comment: and what would be their maximum?

Comment: That doesn't matter - either the container, none at all or something in between. As initially said, their content will never be so long that it will exceed the containers width.